# How I remove white rows in report of Visual Studio?

Tags: reporting-services

I created a report in the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. My problem is in the result.
I used a table for show the result of my report. The last column was created unnecessary white rows. Look the example:

```
City         | Streets         | number
-------------------------------------------------------
Porto Alegre | Osvaldo Aranha  | 100
             |                 | 101
             |                 | 
             |                 |  
             |                 |  102
             |                 |  103
             |                 |  
             |                 |  104
```

How I can remove this white rows?

Answer (score 1):

I discover the answer. In the "Row Groups", I remove the group "Details" and solved this problem.